# Shopify error on querying for collections/products ::Field 'products'/'collections' doesn't exist on type 'Shop'

Tags: android, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

I am getting this error while fetching products with Android Shopify SDK com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3:3.2.3

```
Error: "errors":[{"message":"Field 'products' doesn't exist on type 'Shop'","locations":[{"line":1,"column":7}]
```

My Queries. First 2 are associated with collections and products are getting this error. Next 2 gives response:

1.

```
{shop{collections(first:10){edges{node{id,title}}}}}
```

Err: Field 'collections' doesn't exist on type 'Shop'

2. `{shop{products(first:10,sortKey:RELEVANCE,reverse:false,query:"vendor:'MyCommunity Store'"){edges{cursor,node{id,title,description,descriptionHtml,vendor,productType,createdAt,updatedAt,tags,options(first:1){id,name,values},images(first:1){edges{node{id,src,altText}}},variants(first:1){edges{node{id,title,price,compareAtPrice,weight,weightUnit,availableForSale,selectedOptions{name,value},image{id,src,altText},product{id,images(first:1){edges{node{id,src,altText}}},options{id,name,values},vendor}}}}}}}}}`

Err: Field 'products' doesn't exist on type 'Shop'

3.

```
{shop{name}}
```

Response: {"data":{"shop":{"name":"Store.myCommunity.Today"}}}

4.

```
mutation{customerAccessTokenCreate(input:{email:"xx@yy.com",password:"xxxx"}){customerAccessToken{accessToken,expiresAt},userErrors{field,message}}}
```

Response: {"data":{"customerAccessTokenCreate":{"customerAccessToken":{"accessToken":"xxxx","expiresAt":"2023-08-30T03:50:52Z"},"userErrors":[]}}}

I would also like to point out the same query works on tools like jMeter/Postman. It also works fine on our iOS and web apps. Its just the android app that has started to see this error since last 5 days. Before this, the android client was able to fetch products. We have changed nothing on android client or the Shopify Settings.

I would also like to point out we faced same issue back in January. Than time again it was only the android client that was getting the same error. After 48 hrs, the android client started fetching the products again without any changes on the client code or shopify dashboard.

These similar posts on the community without any response:
https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/our-apps-where-we-have-integrated-mobile-buy-sdk-stops-working/m-p/2130690

https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/javascript-buy-sdk-error-field-collections-doesn-t-exist-on-shop/m-p/1904606